# Building an author list using datatool in scrartcl

Tags: koma-script, datatool

I am basically trying to rebuild the `revtex4-1` author environment using the `datatool` package in a `scrartcl` document. The point of this is to be able to eventually read in a large list of authors from a .csv file and then automatically format it correctly in my `scrartcl` document, which uses KOMA-script for various other reasons.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{datatool}

%% DEFINE THE AUTHOR DATABASE
\DTLnewdb{longauthors}
\newcommand*{\longauthor}[3]{%
\DTLnewrow{longauthors}%
\DTLnewdbentry{longauthors}{name}{#1}%
\DTLnewdbentry{longauthors}{affiliation}{#2}%
\DTLnewdbentry{longauthors}{email}{#3}%
}

%% ADD THE AUTHORS
\longauthor{A.N. AUTHOR}{Organization}{Email: address@author.com}
\longauthor{A.N. OTHER-AUTHOR}{Other-Organization}{}
\longauthor{A. THIRD-AUTHOR}{Other-Organization}{}

%% GET UNIQUE AFFILIATIONS
\newcommand*{\uniqueaffils}{}
\DTLforeach*{longauthors}{\name=name,\affil=affiliation,\email=email}{%
  \DTLifSubString{\uniqueaffils}{\affil}%
  {}% do nothing, already in list
  {% add to list
    \ifdefempty{\uniqueaffils}%
    {% first element of list
        \eappto\uniqueaffils{\affil}%
    }%
    {% append to list
        \eappto\uniqueaffils{, \affil}%
    }%
  }%
}

%% MAKE AUTHOR LIST
\newcommand*{\authorlist}{}
\DTLforeach*{longauthors}{\name=name, \affil=affiliation, \email=email}{%
  \DTLifSubString{\authorlist}{\name} % make sure author is unique
  {}% do nothing, already in list
  {% add to list
    \ifdefempty{\authorlist}%
    {% first element of list
        \eappto\authorlist{\name}%
    }%
    {% append to list
        \eappto\authorlist{, \name}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\authorlist

List of unique affiliations: \uniqueaffils.
   
\end{document}
```

which produces output that looks like this:

[image: Current Output]

How can I transform the code above to change this list into the desired format:

[image: Desired Output]

Namely, the changes that I am most concerned about:

1. How can I add an "and" between the final two authors?
2. How can I keep track of and assign the affiliation for each author, from my numbered list of unique affiliations?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: For your second question, you may want to take a look at the approach to this problem here: [How to use loop for creating defined number of newcommands counting authors](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/688000). Expl3 also provides fairly straightforward built-in ways of answering question 1.

Comment: Welcome, I also wanted to guide you to my very similar question, which Alan answered in a satisfying and comprehensive way. But he was faster himself ;) It works great and `expl3` syntax is made for cases like this, especially if you read in a csv-list with `\seq_set_from_clist:` functions.

Comment: Oh interesting! Thanks for sharing this link, I'll check it out!